# System.out in java

Tags: java, system.out

how to carry test on the class below with System.out in java - where and how should i put the System.out script

```
public class DtaPlusMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private double a = 1.0;
    private double b = 2.0;
    private double c = 3.0;

    private DtaPlusMethods()
    {// Empty Constructor   
    }

    private double Mean()
    {
        c = (a + b)/2;
        return(c);
    }       

}
```

Comment: You have to ask you first what is the entry point of your program. Then you can just call it from there.

Comment: am learning - it just a test in an excercise

Comment: in your main add `System.out.println(new DtaPlusMethods().Mean());`

Comment: tell your teacher that method names should be lower case, and empty constructors are not necessary so should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DtaPlusMethods {
    private double a = 1.0;
    private double b = 2.0;
    private double c = 3.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DtaPlusMethods thisClass= new DtaPlusMethods();
        System.out.println(thisClass.Mean());

    }

    private double Mean()
    {
        c = (a + b)/2;
        return(c);
    }  
}
```